# Bounded search tree: k-Vertex cover with $\Delta(G) = 2$

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, parameterized-complexity

I am studying the book "Parametrized Algorithms" and it suggests a bounded search tree algorithm for k-Vertex Cover. Basically we look at a vertex v and say :
*Either v will cover it's incident edges or it has to be it's neighbors $N(V)$ so either $v$ or $N(v)$ will end up in the cover*.
That's 2 choices , we build a tree with these .
The total running time is summarized by this relation :
$T(k) =T(k-1) + T(k-N(v)) + O(n)$
Considering the interesting case is $N(v) \geq 2$ then $k - N(v) \leq k-2$
so we get:
$$T(k) =T(k-1) + T(k-2) + O(n)$$
Now the book says that ***"Vertex Cover can be solved optimally in polynomial
time when the maximum degree of a graph is at most 2".***
*"Thus, we branch only on the vertices of degree at least 3, which immediately
brings us to the following upper bound on the number of leaves in a search
tree:"*
[image]

**Since the are no vertices with degree 3 or more how do we branch on these ?** What am I missing here?

Comment: why the first two recursive formulae include an O(n)?

Answer (score 2):

Once all vertices have degree $<=2$ you don't branch on them - you just apply a standard polynomial time algorithm to solve it.

Since your graph consists of a disjoint set of cycles and line graphs, the min vertex cover for components which are line graphs would be $⌊C/2⌋$ and $⌈C/2⌉$ for cycles where $C$ is the size of the component. Therefore this can be solved in $O(n+m)$ as the problem just reduces to finding the size of components within a graph.

The recurrence given is for reducing the graph to a form where all vertices have degree $<=2$ as you either remove the current vertex or remove 3 of its neighbours. Doing this repeatedly will eventually lead you to a graph where all vertices have degree $<=2$

Comment: "you either remove the current vertex or remove 3 of its neighbors" should be "you either remove the vertex or remove all of its neighbors".

Comment: Also, "doing this repeatedly will eventually lead you to a graph where all vertices have degree <= 2" should be "doing this repeatedly will eventually lead you to a graph where all vertices have degree <= 2 or a k-vertex cover problem with k <=2"